# How change completed work of work items via a time sheet in TFS 2010

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I want to have an easy editor to fill the time sheet by developers. 
The main problem with increasing the completed work is that we can't make changes for past days.

I've found this great tool at codeplex: http://tfstimesheet.codeplex.com/
but it seems it's not working on TFS 2010, since it's last release is for 2009 and is documented to use on TFS 2008.

Is there any other way to fill the time sheet in TFS 2010?

Answer (score 3):

Tfs doesn't provide time-sheet functionality and has no concept of date in regard to completed work (in default templates atleast).

Any tool including the one you linked relies on its own datastore and timesheet frontend to fill data into tfs workitems and attach required timesheet information and save it into datastore. Depending on its sofistication it may or may not detect changes done directly in workitem (most likly will not).

Quick google search 'tfs timesheet application' returns several options, i have used chrono and it generaly gets the job done, cant say anything on install and configuration as i was not involved with those.

http://tfstimesheets.codeplex.com/

http://www.teamexpand.com/product/tx-chrono

Comment: The teamexpand one seems to be useful, I'll check it.

Comment: http://www.teamexpand.com/product/tx-chrono - it supports all new TFS versions (2008, 2010, 2012, 2013), deployment types and process templates. Basic features are time reporting, time approval and bidirectional sync with TFS.